# Machine translation transformer output - "unknown" tokens?

Tags: nlp, transformer

Cross post from my original post in Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69595863/machine-translation-transformer-output-unknown-tokens

Based on the feedback , I have now updated my approach to use WordPiece from Huggingface's pretrained BERT tokenizers. However, I still run into "unk" tokens when translating. I am curious why that still happens? I thought that WordPiece would try to decode without outputting any "unk" tokens.

This is how I tokenized my data, I am using German to english for the translation task.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
bert_tokenizer_en = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
bert_tokenizer_de = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-german-cased",do_lower_case=True)
```

Example out:

`````
ground truth = ['a', 'girl', 'in', 'a', 'jean', 'dress', 'is', 'walking', 'along', 'a', 'raised', 'balance', 'beam', '.']

predicted = ['a', 'girl', 'in', 'a', '<unk>', 'costume', 'is', 'jumping', 'on', 'a', 'clothesline', '.', '<eos>']
````
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According Hugging Face documentation for BERT, the default [vocab_size](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertConfig.vocab_size) is 30522. The token 'jean' is not in those top 30522 tokens.